# DAQ Software Alternative

Tags: visual-c++, labview

I wanted to get NI USB-6008 DAQ but I don't want to burn a hole in my wallet buying LABView. Are there any alternatives to LABView as DAQ software for this card? Is it possible to use Visual C++ Express or OS software like BioMOBIUS with this DAQ card?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the USB-6008 supports both ANSI-C or .NET control WITHOUT Labview, LabWindows, or Measurement Studio although these are certainly great options as well.

You'd use the NI-DAQmx library.

Reference:

See page 7 and 8 of the USB-6008 manual here:
http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/371303l.pdf

Comment: I have a C++ wrapper for nidaq-mx (for analog acquisition functions), let me know if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks crlanglois. And I may be interested Ben, once I have the DAQ in hand.

Comment: so having said this, I would like to program the DAQ board with ANSI-C. Any IDEs that are good to do this with? I was thinking about using 'The Eclipse C/C++ Development Tools' with Eclipse.. @BenVoigt I would definitley appreciate having the C++ wrapper. Let me know what I gotta do to get it.

Comment: @moesef: I uploaded it [on CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/8840/2150)

Answer (score 1):

NI offer [Measurement Studio](http://www.ni.com/mstudio/) that allows you to use their DAQ devices with Visual Studio. I'm not sure if you can use it with Visual C++ Express but as it's a .net library I'd expect it to work.

From the NI Website:

> Measurement Studio is an integrated measurement solution of tools
>   created specifically for V isual Studio .NET programmers. It is
>   designed for engineers and scientists building test, measurement, and
>   control applications in Visual Studio 2010/2008/2005.

Measurment Studio is not free (as pointed out by @BenVoigt, thanks Ben) but is less than half the price of LabVIEW Base. I understand that it will give you access to many of the visual controls and indicators similar to LabVIEW but this does come at a price and if they are not needed then there are better options.

For a free option the NI-DAQmx library as mentioned by @crlanglois looks a much better choice.

Comment: He said he didn't want to burn a hole in his wallet.

Comment: Yes @BenVoigt I had missed that Measurement Studio has to be purchased. The NI-DAQmx library as mentioned by crlanglois looks to be your best option.

Comment: Well thanks for the info Swinders... if Measurement Studio is substantially cheaper than LabView, I might be inclined to get it... I'll have to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the cost effective alternative is pyDAQmx : http://pythonhosted.org/PyDAQmx/

Answer (score 0):

[Visual DAQ](http://visualdaq.com/) is a customized alternative to LABView.